# Как удалить из текста символ "@" если их больше 2-х?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, веб-программирование

В переменную приходит текст который может содержать в себе 2 и больше подряд символов `@`.

**Пример 1:**

Нужно удалять именно если в тексте подряд два и больше символов `@`.

**Например текст содержит:**

1. 2@2 - не трогать.
2. а если вот так @@ - удалить оба символа.

Нужно удалить все символы в строке которая содержит подряд две и больше собак, или одну собаку после которой нет символа.

Но текст может содержать два примера сразу и важно чтоб текст из первого примера остался невредим.

**Пример 2:**

Возможен такой вариант: если в строке перед и после собаки есть символы не пробелы, все остальное удалять.

**Варианты которые нужно убрать:**

1. r@;
2. @;
3. @r;
4. @@@@@@@;

Кто такое уже делал подскажите как решить?

Comment: а если будет 3 собаки? Т.е. "@@@" - что должно получиться? Одна собака ("@") или ноль собак ("")? Если ноль собак, то регулярку так и писать: `/@@+/` (т.е. `preg_replace('/@@+/', '', '@ @@ @@@ @a@')`)

Comment: а если `@d@` тоже заменять? либо только когда символы подряд идут?

Comment: @BOPOH, просто если собака после неё символ то ничего не делать, а если собака после которой собаки или пробел то удалять собаки

Comment: @Grundy, если такой случай то тоже да

Comment: нужно больше примеров возможных строк и ожидаемых для них результатов

Comment: @Grundy, я просто оставляю имейлы в тексте но случаии когда имейла, нет идут только после тех что есть : и могут выглядеть ток в виде оставшихся сиволов собаки перед которой может быть один символ, или пробел и после пробел или другие собаки.

Comment: ну тогда можно так: `(preg_replace('/@@+|@(?=(\s|\r|\n|$))/', '', '@a @ @@ @@@@@ @a@')` (на выходе получим *"@a    @a"*). А если удалять если перед собакой ничего нет, тогда так: `preg_replace('/@@+|@(?=\s|$|\r|\n)|(?<=\s|^|\r|\n)@/', '', '@a a@a @a @ @@ @@@@@ @a@')` (на выходе *"a a@a a    a"*)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Comment: @alexander barakin, 2 человека поставили минус и 2 плюс. И ещё 3 понравился ответ.  То есть те люди которые плюсанули, оно им не полезно ? И на вопрос дан ответ уже. Смысл закрывать ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999, 1. вижу лишь один «минус» у вопроса. 2. вот именно — ответ вам уже дан. кому-либо ещё, с моей точки зрения, этот вопрос вряд ли может быть хоть чем-то полезен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях есть конструкция {x,y}, где x - минимальное количество символов, а y - максимальное. то есть в вашем случае `preg_replace('/@{2,}/', '', $string_with_at))` заменит совпадения, где 2 или больше @, а `preg_replace('/@{2}/', '', $string_with_at))` - заменит только двойное вхождение.

Comment: посмотрите комментарии, такая регулярка не подходит

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за участие